# Is it possible to get a backward Dynamic Slice in Frama-C?

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

I get a backward slice from Frama-c, but looks like its a static slice and not a dynamic slice.

Is a specific option in frama-c to get a dynamic backward slice?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing#Dynamic_slicing),

> A dynamic slice contains all statements that actually affect the value of a variable at a program point for a particular execution of the program rather than all statements that may have affected the value of a variable at a program point for any arbitrary execution of the program.

Frama-C's slicing plug-in is conditioned by the values from the value analysis plug-in, which it takes on faith to represent all the values that happen for an execution in the set of executions of interest. In order to configure Frama-C's slicing plug-in for dynamic slicing, you simply need to have the value analysis correspond to a single execution. Using a `main` function without inputs, no `volatile` variables, no calls to unknown functions and passing the option `-slevel 999999999` to `frama-c` should make the value analysis behave as a C interpreter along the single execution of the program of your choice, as documented in [this previous answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17577069/139746), [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/08/29/CompCert-gets-a-safe-interpreter-mode) and in [this article](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/nfm12.pdf).